# using $.each jquery to create html select option in ajax success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a bootstrap modal that contains a form. This form will be using a lot of data from my database, So I use php to get them like this :

```
public function get_view_for_inspection_report_belum_eor(){
    $q = $this->inspection->get_view_for_inspection_report_belum_eor();
    echo json_encode($q);
}
```

It gives me a new json code like this :

```
[{
"NO_INSPECTION": "5",
"NO_SURAT": "00005",
"DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION": "2016-01-04 21:00:37",
"NAMA_SURVEYOR1": "surveyor",
"NAMA_SURVEYOR2": "surveyor",
"INSULATION": "3",
"VESSEL": "MV WAN HAI 171",
"PREFIX": "EOLU",
"SERIAL_NUMBER": "1111111",
"NAMA_CLEAN_ITEM": "SURFONIC AGM 550",
"TARIFF": "0.00",
"COMMENTS": "Test Surveyor 1\r\n\r\nTest Surveyor 2"
 }, {
"NO_INSPECTION": "4",
"NO_SURAT": "00004",
"DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION": "2016-01-04 19:33:23",
"NAMA_SURVEYOR1": "surveyor",
"NAMA_SURVEYOR2": null,
"INSULATION": "3",
"VESSEL": "WAN HAI 202",
"PREFIX": "EOLU",
"SERIAL_NUMBER": "1111111",
"NAMA_CLEAN_ITEM": "REVERTING",
"TARIFF": "0.00",
"COMMENTS": "Test Saja"
 }, {
"NO_INSPECTION": "3",
"NO_SURAT": "00003",
"DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION": "2016-01-04 19:26:15",
"NAMA_SURVEYOR1": "surveyor",
"NAMA_SURVEYOR2": null,
"INSULATION": "2",
"VESSEL": "WAN HAI 202",
"PREFIX": "EOLU",
"SERIAL_NUMBER": "1111111",
"NAMA_CLEAN_ITEM": "SUBASA",
"TARIFF": "0.00",
"COMMENTS": "Test surveyor 1"
 }, {
"NO_INSPECTION": "2",
"NO_SURAT": "00002",
"DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION": "2016-01-04 15:15:23",
"NAMA_SURVEYOR1": "surveyor",
"NAMA_SURVEYOR2": null,
"INSULATION": "3",
"VESSEL": "WAN HAI 202",
"PREFIX": "EOLU",
"SERIAL_NUMBER": "2222222",
"NAMA_CLEAN_ITEM": "TEXANOL ESTER ALKOHOL",
"TARIFF": "0.00",
"COMMENTS": "Test"
 }, {
"NO_INSPECTION": "1",
"NO_SURAT": "00001",
"DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION": "2016-01-04 19:13:07",
"NAMA_SURVEYOR1": "surveyor",
"NAMA_SURVEYOR2": "surveyor",
"INSULATION": "1",
"VESSEL": "MV.WAN HAI 171",
"PREFIX": "EOLU",
"SERIAL_NUMBER": "1111111",
"NAMA_CLEAN_ITEM": "N-BUTANOL",
"TARIFF": "0.00",
"COMMENTS": "Test survey 1\r\nTest survey 2"
}]
```

This is my ajax

```
$('#add_eir').click(function () {
    action = "TAMBAH";
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?= site_url('admin/c_admin_eir/get_view_for_inspection_report_belum_eor'); ?>",
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(response){
            $("#dynamic_no_inspection").find(':first-child').remove();

            //  CREATE A SELECT OPTION
            $("#dynamic_no_inspection").html('<select data-placeholder="Pilih no inpeksi..." class="form-control chosen-select" name="no_inspection" id="no_inspection" style="width:250px;" tabindex="2">' +
            '<option></option>' +

             // How to create an option based ajax response  ?

            '</select>');
        }
    });


 });
```

Now, the question is? How to make the option based the ajax response using jquery. I expected the `<option>` be like this :

```
<option value="response[i].NO_INSPECTION" . "> response[i].NO_SURAT ( response[i].PREFIX - response[i].SERIAL_NUMBER ) </option>
```

I knew in php, just loop using

```
foreach ($all_inspection_belum_eor as $row) :
   echo "<option value=" . "$row->NO_INSPECTION" . "> $row->NO_SURAT ( $row->PREFIX - $row->SERIAL_NUMBER ) </option>";
endforeach;
```

For any help, it so appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can refer below code to take an idea about how we can append an `<option>` dynamically to a`<select>` box:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dynamic_no_inspection").html('<select data-placeholder="Pilih no inpeksi..." class="form-control chosen-select" name="no_inspection" id="no_inspection" style="width:250px;" tabindex="2">' +
           '</select>');
  
  var response = [{
"NO_INSPECTION": "5",
"NO_SURAT": "00005",
"DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION": "2016-01-04 21:00:37",
"NAMA_SURVEYOR1": "surveyor",
"NAMA_SURVEYOR2": "surveyor",
"INSULATION": "3",
"VESSEL": "MV WAN HAI 171",
"PREFIX": "EOLU",
"SERIAL_NUMBER": "1111111",
"NAMA_CLEAN_ITEM": "SURFONIC AGM 550",
"TARIFF": "0.00",
"COMMENTS": "Test Surveyor 1\r\n\r\nTest Surveyor 2"
 }, {
"NO_INSPECTION": "4",
"NO_SURAT": "00004",
"DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION": "2016-01-04 19:33:23",
"NAMA_SURVEYOR1": "surveyor",
"NAMA_SURVEYOR2": null,
"INSULATION": "3",
"VESSEL": "WAN HAI 202",
"PREFIX": "EOLU",
"SERIAL_NUMBER": "1111111",
"NAMA_CLEAN_ITEM": "REVERTING",
"TARIFF": "0.00",
"COMMENTS": "Test Saja"
 }, {
"NO_INSPECTION": "3",
"NO_SURAT": "00003",
"DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION": "2016-01-04 19:26:15",
"NAMA_SURVEYOR1": "surveyor",
"NAMA_SURVEYOR2": null,
"INSULATION": "2",
"VESSEL": "WAN HAI 202",
"PREFIX": "EOLU",
"SERIAL_NUMBER": "1111111",
"NAMA_CLEAN_ITEM": "SUBASA",
"TARIFF": "0.00",
"COMMENTS": "Test surveyor 1"
 }, {
"NO_INSPECTION": "2",
"NO_SURAT": "00002",
"DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION": "2016-01-04 15:15:23",
"NAMA_SURVEYOR1": "surveyor",
"NAMA_SURVEYOR2": null,
"INSULATION": "3",
"VESSEL": "WAN HAI 202",
"PREFIX": "EOLU",
"SERIAL_NUMBER": "2222222",
"NAMA_CLEAN_ITEM": "TEXANOL ESTER ALKOHOL",
"TARIFF": "0.00",
"COMMENTS": "Test"
 }, {
"NO_INSPECTION": "1",
"NO_SURAT": "00001",
"DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION": "2016-01-04 19:13:07",
"NAMA_SURVEYOR1": "surveyor",
"NAMA_SURVEYOR2": "surveyor",
"INSULATION": "1",
"VESSEL": "MV.WAN HAI 171",
"PREFIX": "EOLU",
"SERIAL_NUMBER": "1111111",
"NAMA_CLEAN_ITEM": "N-BUTANOL",
"TARIFF": "0.00",
"COMMENTS": "Test survey 1\r\nTest survey 2"
}]
  
  //code to create an options
  
  for(i=0;i<response.length;i++)
  {
    var optionValue = response[i].NO_INSPECTION;
    var optionText = response[i].NO_SURAT +' ('+ response[i].PREFIX +'-'+ response[i].SERIAL_NUMBER +')';
    
    var optionString = "<option value='"+optionValue+"'>"+optionText+"</option>";
    $("#dynamic_no_inspection select").append($(optionString));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dynamic_no_inspection">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#add_eir').click(function() {

  //get select element
  var $select = $('#no_inspection');

  //clear current options
  $select.children().remove();

  //loop through response array
  $.each(response, function() {
    //create new option and add to select
    var $opt = $('<option/>');
    $opt.val(this.NO_INSPECTION);
    $opt.text(this.NO_SURAT + '(' + this.PREFIX + '-' + this.SERIAL_NUMBER + ')');
    $select.append($opt);
  });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qspbb4wg/

If you use jQuery.each function then this is each object in the array. Move the code above into your ajax.success handler.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the native array methods to perform the task so you can reduce your array into a single string that can be innerHTML'd or .html'd into the select list once processing is complete.

```js
var options = [{
  "NO_INSPECTION": "5",
  "NO_SURAT": "00005",
  "DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION": "2016-01-04 21:00:37",
  "NAMA_SURVEYOR1": "surveyor",
  "NAMA_SURVEYOR2": "surveyor",
  "INSULATION": "3",
  "VESSEL": "MV WAN HAI 171",
  "PREFIX": "EOLU",
  "SERIAL_NUMBER": "1111111",
  "NAMA_CLEAN_ITEM": "SURFONIC AGM 550",
  "TARIFF": "0.00",
  "COMMENTS": "Test Surveyor 1\r\n\r\nTest Surveyor 2"
}, {
  "NO_INSPECTION": "4",
  "NO_SURAT": "00004",
  "DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION": "2016-01-04 19:33:23",
  "NAMA_SURVEYOR1": "surveyor",
  "NAMA_SURVEYOR2": null,
  "INSULATION": "3",
  "VESSEL": "WAN HAI 202",
  "PREFIX": "EOLU",
  "SERIAL_NUMBER": "1111111",
  "NAMA_CLEAN_ITEM": "REVERTING",
  "TARIFF": "0.00",
  "COMMENTS": "Test Saja"
}]

// this function will loop through your option array and return a single html 
// string using the native Array.reduce method
function createOptions(options) {
  return options.reduce(function(ret, option) {
    // in here you have access to any of the option properties
    return ret + '<option value="' + option['NO_INSPECTION'] + '" . "> ( ' + option['PREFIX'] + ' - ' + option['SERIAL_NUMBER'] + ' ) </option>';
  }, '');
}

// pretend this is your ajax callback (it will happen some time in the first second of load
window.setTimeout(function(){
  
  // write the option html to the select element
  $('#dynamic_no_inspection').html(createOptions(options));

}, Math.random() * 1000 );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dynamic_no_inspection">
  <option>please select</option>
</select>
```